# Why can I access this Oracle table from the query worksheet but not from a package?

Tags: oracle

I'm working with two schemas on the same database, SCHEMA_A and SCHEMA_B. I'm logged in as SCHEMA_A and can query SCHEMA_B.TABLE_NAME from the SQL worksheet in SQL Developer. I then tried to create a package in SCHEMA_A containing a procedure that queries SCHEMA_B.TABLE_NAME and get an error that SCHEMA_B.TABLE_NAME doesn't exist. Why would I be able to query it as SCHEMA_A but not create a package in SCHEMA_A with a procedure that queries it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you described sounds like this:

- in order to be able to access table owned by another user, you have to get **privileges** do to so
- these privileges can be granted

  - directly from SCHEMA_B to SCHEMA_A, or
  - via role: first SCHEMA_B granted access on TABLE_NAME to that role, and then role was granted to SCHEMA_A
- doing so, you are allowed to access SCHEMA_B.TABLE_NAME from SQL layer or anonymous PL/SQL blocks, but **not from named PL/SQL procedures** (i.e. stored procedures, functions, packages, triggers)
- it means that SCHEMA_B has to **directly** grant privileges to SCHEMA_A, not via role

Is that your case?

Comment: It might be, but I don't have access to SCHEMA_B to check, I'll have to coordinate with the DBA. I'll let you know!

Comment: You nailed it, thanks!